# NodeJS cannot find custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to export a module to my routes file.

My file tree goes like

```
routes.js
app.js
controllers/users.js
            posts.js
```

on my `app.js` I exported `var route = require('./routes');` and that works.
now on my `routes.js` I tried to export `require('./controllers');`.

But it keeps telling me that it `cannot find module controllers`.

Doing this works:

```
require('./controllers/users')
```

But I am trying to follow expressjs sample initial projects format.
And it is bugging me because the example of `expressjs` shows: (express routes is a folder)

```
var routes = require('./routes');
```

and loads it like

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

with no error. and that `./routes` is a folder. I am just following the same principle.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to `require` a directory, it expects there to be an `index.js` file in that directory. Otherwise, you have to simply require individual files: `require('./controllers/users')`. Alternatively, you can create an `index.js` file in the `controllers` directory and add the following:

```
module.exports.users = require('./users');
module.exports.posts = require('./posts');
```

and then import: `var c = require('./controllers');`. You can then use them via `c.users` and `c.posts`.

Comment: So how do I call the exports I have on the users.js?

Comment: @majimboo Not sure if I understand your question. [See here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object) for further details on the module object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how require() works.

In your case it fails to find a file named controller.js so it assumes it's a directory and then searches for `index.js` specifically. That is why it works in the express example.

For your usecase you can do something like this -

```
var controllerPath = __dirname + '/controllers';
fs.readdirSync(controllerPath).forEach(function(file) {
    require(controllerPath + '/' + file);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

> LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
>
> 1. If X/package.json is a file,    a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.    b. let M = X + (json main field)    c.
>    LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
> 2. **If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP**
> 3. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP

So, if a directory has an index.js, it will load that.

Now, look @ expressjs

http://expressjs.com/guide.html

> create : myapp/routes
>
> create : myapp/routes/index.js

Taking some time to really read how modules work is time well spent.  [Read here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)